# Linq to Entities with a referenced property

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I'm doing an application with a master data management with EF 5.0, and I want to keep it as generic as possible, because loading the items, saving them, etc are always the same.

My entities look something like this:

```
// IDBEntity.cs
public interface IDBEntity<T>
{
    public int ID { get; }

    ...
}

// Product.cs (Generated)
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

// ProductExtension.cs
public patial class Product : IDBEntity<Product>
{
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return ProductID
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to do a query for the ID in some cases, but the problem is you can't do a LINQ to Entity query with a custom property.

```
public class MasterDataViewModel<T> :  where T : IDBEntity, new()
{
    public T CurrentItem { get; set; }

    public void ReloadItem(int id)
    {
        using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            // This is the problem
            CurrentItem = context.Set<T>.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id)
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this maybe with an expression that points to the real ID? Something like this:

```
public interface IDBEntity<T>
{
    public Expression<Func<T, int>> { get; }
}

public patial class Product : IDBEntity<Product>
{
    public Expression<Func<Product, int>> ID
    {
        get
        {
            return x => x.ProductID
        }
    }
}
```

Are there other better solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method in DbSet

```
public class MasterDataViewModel<T> :  where T : IDBEntity, new()
{
    public T CurrentItem { get; set; }

    public void ReloadItem(int id)
    {
        using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            CurrentItem = context.Set<T>().Find(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the same case we have used this code:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

So your `Product` will look like

```
public class Product : BaseEntity
{    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And `MasterDataViewModel`

```
public class MasterDataViewModel<T> :  where T : BaseEntity, new()
{
    public T CurrentItem { get; set; }

    public void ReloadItem(int id)
    {
        using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            CurrentItem = context.Set<T>.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only work if you are doing a database first approach